# Does anybody know if JSystem can be used for testing Java applets?

Tags: applet, automated-tests

Does anybody know if JSystem (open source code based on JUnit and ANT for automated tests) can be used for testing Java applets?  All I need is Yes or No and if possible a link for reading about it.  If you are familiar with another tool that can be used, please give me a name or a link to reading about it.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about JSystem but you can take a look at this tool code.google.com/p/fest/ which supports applet testing, refer: http://fest.easytesting.org/swing/wiki/pmwiki.php?n=FEST-Swing.FESTAppletViewer

Answer (score 0):

Of course.
it supports both Autoit usage or Swing apps, using jemmy.